# Disable "find" shortcut (CTRL-SHIFT-F) in gnome terminal

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-terminal

I'm currently running ubuntu 14.04 (with compiz window manager) and have difficulty disabling a shortcut while gnome-terminal is in focus. It's regarding the (annoying and useless) "find" window which pops up after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

This keybinding is **not** mentioned in:

```
1) ccsm            -> general options -> keybindings
2) ccsm            -> commands -> keybindings
2) gconf-editor    -> /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings
4) dconf-editor    -> /org/gnome/terminal <-- entry does not exist
5) gnome-terminal  -> edit -> keyboard shortcuts
6) system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> [all entries]
```

I have tried without success:

1. Setting ctrl-shift-F as a shortcut explicitly with different behaviour, 
       e.g. switch tab, in gnome terminal
2. Editing */home/USER/.gtkrc*, *.gtkrc-2.0* and *.gtkrc-3.0* to:

   ```
   binding "CustomNoSearch"
   {
       unbind "<ctrl><shift>f"
   }
   class "*" binding "CustomNoSearch"
   ```
3. Editing */home/USER/.config/gtk-2.0/gtk-keys.css* and *../git-3.0/gtk-keys.css*:

   ```
   @binding-set custom-no-search
   {
       unbind "<ctrl><shift>f";
   }
   GtkEntry {
       gtk-key-bindings: custom-no-search;
   }
   ```
4. Changing *keyboard input method system* from *IBUS* to *None* (system settings->language support->keyboard input method system) disables everything, including ctrl-shift-F, but this is too much.

At this point I have run out of ideas. Where is this behaviour defined? 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The shortcut is defined in [terminal-window.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/master/src/terminal-window.c) (scroll down to line 2427).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just disable it in the [preferences of GNOME Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL71f.png).

Click on the entry under the Shortcut Key column and, when you’re prompted for a new key binding (“New Accelerator...”), press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to disable this by emptying the contents of

`/usr/share/gnome-terminal/find-dialog.ui`

While this is kind of a kludge way to do it, it works without causing any other problems.

It is obviously a good idea to back the file up before emptying it, but it probably isn't anything `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal --reinstall` couldn't fix..

So, in short :

```
# cd /usr/share/gnome-terminal/
# cp find-dialog.ui ~
# >find-dialog.ui
```

And no more find dialog...

Comment: I tried this, but I don't think it disables `gnome-terminal` from capturing the key sequence, just from running the find dialog.

Comment: Right, but the resulting inaction of `gnome-terminal` allows something else to subsequently pick up on the keystroke without additional, unwanted actions.